# Linking to assets outside publick folder in laravel + forge

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5, forge

My browser does not find images defined in the css file. As an example i use this:

> background-image: url(../../../resources/assets/img/logo.png); }

It is found on my local (windows machine, no web dir defined), but not on my test server.

I use laravel 5 + forge + elixer.  In forge i defined my web directory as "/public" .

My folder structure is like:

- app
- config
- etc
- public

  - css

    - all-12345678.css
  - js

    - all-12345678.js
- resources

  - assets

    - img

      - image-1.png
      - image-2.png
      - image-x.png

In my view i link to the css and js file this way. The files are found by the browser:

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('') }}{{elixir('css/all.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="{{ URL::asset('')}}{{ elixir('js/all.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can i link to the assets in the css file? Or should ik replace them to the public folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure) the `resources` folder is not made for what you want:

`The resources directory contains your views, raw assets (LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript), and localization files.`

Furthermore Laravel explicitly uses the `public` folder as document root so that nobody can access files/assets outside of this directory. You better make a folder `images` inside the `public` folder and put in your images there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @codedge, you should access your images from a public folder. If you're already using gulp, you could just add a copy job to gulpfile.js. something like:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
        mix.copy('resources/images', 'public/images');
});
```

Comment: @codedge was just a liitle quicker. The issue with the elixer for images is that i can't get it working for references to images in .css files. In blade it self i can understand.